# Steps to publish a craft website from local to server

Tags: server

is there any resource that list all the steps to publish a local finished website to the final server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably depends most on your hosting but following these instructions are probably your best bet: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/installing The only exception being instead of "installing" you'd move your files up and import your database.

If you are using github, it's as easy as "pulling" your code to your production server and importing the database into production database as well (local mysql, cloud db etc.)

You'll probably be best off looking at http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/multi-environment-configs so you can create settings for both your local environment and production.

**Here's an example of a sample craft database file:** https://gist.github.com/mccombs/5e17c84743a25dafddb9

**Here's an example of a sample craft general config file:**
https://gist.github.com/mccombs/b6a161cabc064d1f51b3

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for yor response. So i have to move files, create and import database and edit config file to connect to db and that´s it? I think that i have to re-install craft in the server to update some paths and settings ( like Modx for example ).

Comment: Pretty much. I edit my config and db files so I can run the same codebase on my local environment (MAMP) and production. Inside of that you can set your site URLs to be dynamic. I added two gists to my answer that shows how you can do this.